# Edit multiple entities in one form

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Entity `Question` and form type for editing Question `QuestionType`. I can successfull edit one Question. Now i create a link for editing all Questions.

I would like to edit all Questions in one form, how can i handle this? I try to use collections, but i don't know how to map a single question in a form collection and I'm not sure if that's the right approach.

My `QuestionType` look like:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $categories = $this->entityManager->getRepository('MyAppBundle:QuestionCategory')->findByIsActive(true);

        $builder->add('category', 'entity', array(
                        'class' => 'MyAppBundle:QuestionCategory',
                        'choices' => $categories,
                        'label' => 'category',
                        'translation_domain' => 'messages',
                        'multiple' => false,
                        'empty_value' => 'msg.pleaseSelect',
                        'expanded' => false))
                ->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations', array(
                            'fields' => array(
                                'text' => array(
                                    'field_type' => 'textarea',
                                    'label' => 'hintText',
                                    'attr' => array('class' => 'rte')
                                ),
                                'explanation' => array(
                                    'field_type' => 'textarea',
                                    'label' => 'title',
                                    'attr' => array('class' => '')
                                )
                            )
                ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'My\AppBundle\Entity\Question',
        ));
    }
```

My Controller with action to edit all Questions, look like:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$questions = $em->getRepository('MyAppBundle:Question')->findAll();

/**
  * -- Here is my problem , how can i my $questions into form? --- 
**/          
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('questions', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new QuestionType() ,
            'allow_add' => false,
            'allow_delete' => false,
            'label' => false)
    )
    ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'))
    ->getForm();


$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
}

return $this->render('MyAppBundle:Question:editAllQuestions.html.twig', array("form" => $form->createView()));
```

Has anyone a hint or approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, what you probably want to do is:

```
$form->setData(array('questions' => $yourQuestionArray));
```

Just after `->getForm()` but before `->handleRequest($request)`.

Or you could pass it as an option to `createFormBuilder()` like so:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder(array('questions' => $yourQuestionArray))
    ->add(...)
```

They both do the same thing.

Ordinarily when you create a form class (which it looks like what you're doing with `QuestionType`), you provide a `data_class` configuration option ([see documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes)) that defines what the form uses as its model.

What you're doing in your controller is creating a kind of "anonymous" form that doesn't have an associated data class ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class), this looks like what you're doing in your controller). In which case its data is an array (similarly if you called `$form->getData()` you'd get an array back).

Comment: thank you a lot for your suppoert, this solve my issue