# Symfony Edit and persist multiple entities on one form

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have an entity called Objective and its property called 'weight' and I can edit one objective at a time.. and now i want to edit all weights in a single form and persist them in DB using Doctrine..

This issue helped me in bringing all objective weights on a single form..
[Edit multiple entities in one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532695/edit-multiple-entities-in-one-form)

Now I am trickling around on how to save all weight values from the form in DB with a single click of save button..

Below is  my code so far..

This is the  controller action:-

```
/**
 * @Route("/mou/objectives/manage", name="objective_manage")
 */
public function manageAction(Request $request){  

    $objs = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Objective')
    ->findAll();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('weight', 'collection', array(
        'type' => new WeightType() ,
        'allow_add' => false,
        'allow_delete' => false,
        'label' => false))
    ->add('save', 'submit')
    ->getForm();

    $form->setData(array('weight' => $objs));

    /* Till here things are fine */

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        /* **Here I need help how to persist all weight values.. maybe inside a loop.. hence This is the missing piece** */

        foreach($objs as $obj){
            $obj =new Objective();
            $obj = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Objective')->find($obj);
            $obj->setWeight($obj); 
            $em->persist($obj);

        }
        $em->flush();    
        return $this->redirectToRoute('objective_manage');
    } 

    return $this->render('keyobjective/manage.html.twig', array(
        'objs' => $objs,
        'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
}
```

This is the FormType:-

```
class WeightType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('weight','text', array('label' => false));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Objective'
            //'data_class' => null
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_objective';
    }
}
```

and this is twig template:-

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    {{form_start(form)}}

    {{form_label(form.weight,'Enter Weight')}}
    {{form_widget(form.weight)}}

    {{form_end(form)}}
{% endblock %}
```

Any suggested approach..!!

Comment: why are you doing a `$obj =new Objective();` in your loop, then erasing it with an entity retrieved from database ? + you don't need to persist it, persist operation is only used when creating a new object. if you're retrieving an entity from persistence layer, your entity is already persisted, you just need to flush it.

Comment: Thanks.. @VaN but my question was "how to save all weight values from the form in DB with a single click of save button.."

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I figured this out.. after form handle request I created a loop to iterate through the number of objectives being edited and then inside of it another foreach loop which transforms the weight values received from the Form to the setWeight() method one by one:-

```
/**
 * @Route("/mou/objectives/manage", name="objective_manage")
 */
public function manageAction(Request $request){  

    $objs = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Objective')
    ->findAll();

$count = count($objs);

            for($i =0; $i < $count; $i++){
                $objsarray =  new Objective();
            }

            $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('weight', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new WeightType() ,
                'allow_add' => false,
                'allow_delete' => false,
                'options' => array('label' => false),
                ))
            ->add('save', 'submit')
            ->getForm();

            $form->setData(array('weight' => $objs));
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                for($i=0; $i < count($objs); $i++){
                    $obj = new Objective();
                    $obj = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Objective')->find($objs[$i]);
                    $weight = $form->get('weight')->get($i)->getData();

                    foreach($weight as $val){
                        $obj->setWeight($val);
                        $em->persist($obj);
                    }           
                }
                $em->flush();
                $this->addFlash(
                    'notice',
                    'Objective weight updated'
                    );
                return $this->redirectToRoute('objective_manage');
            }
            return $this->render('keyobjective/manage.html.twig', array(
                'objs' => $objs,
                'form' => $form->createView()
                ));
        }
```